# ionic cli 4.5.0 style attributes not applying

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic4

Am a newbie in ionic framework so I would really need your help.
My problem is that whenever I add an attribute to an ionic UI component, it does not work at all. E.g:

```
<button ion-button color="secondary" clear>Secondary Clear</button>
<ion ion-button color="light" outline>Light Outline</button>
 <button ion-button full>Full Button</button>
```

The colors do apply but their attributes do not. Another example is

```
<ion-list>

  <ion-item>
    <ion-label floating>Username</ion-label>
    <ion-input type="text"></ion-input>
  </ion-item>

  <ion-item>
    <ion-label floating>Password</ion-label>
    <ion-input type="password"></ion-input>
  </ion-item>

</ion-list>
```

For this one also the floating attribute is not applying. So what I realize is that the ionic attributes are not actually working for me and I don't know why. This is my app.module.ts file

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
import { RouteReuseStrategy } from '@angular/router';

import { IonicModule, IonicRouteStrategy } from '@ionic/angular';
import { SplashScreen } from '@ionic-native/splash-screen/ngx';
import { StatusBar } from '@ionic-native/status-bar/ngx';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  entryComponents: [],
  imports: [BrowserModule, HttpModule,  IonicModule.forRoot(), AppRoutingModule],
  providers: [
    StatusBar,
    SplashScreen,
    { provide: RouteReuseStrategy, useClass: IonicRouteStrategy }
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Answer (score 0):

your `app.module.ts` should look like this:

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    MyApp,
    HomePage // declear your Page inside declarations
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp),
    HttpClientModule,
    HttpModule,
    IonicStorageModule.forRoot(),

  ],
  bootstrap: [IonicApp],
  entryComponents: [
    MyApp,
    HomePage // ALSO inside bootstrap entryComponemt
  ],
  providers: [
    StatusBar,
    SplashScreen,
    {provide: ErrorHandler, useClass: IonicErrorHandler,}
  ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

this will do the trick for you.